# beautifulsoup4: get href but return "#"

Tags: javascript, html, beautifulsoup

I am using bs4 to get some href from a site.

```
<a class="aaa" target="12345" href="someURL" 
data-track="HOT:SR:HotelModule" tabindex="0"> 
        <span class="visuallyhidden">
        some text here
        </span>
</a>
```

The HTML is like the above.
I can get most of the URL using this code:

```
for URL in res.select('.someClass')
URL.select('a')[0]['href']
```

but some of the return value is #
I have checked the source code of the website and I find the href is really here and it's not #.

What's wrong make me get # but not the url?

Here's [the website](https://www.expedia.com.hk/Hotel-Search?#&destination=HongKong&startDate=&endDate=&regionId=&adults=2) that I am trying.
My problem happened at the hotel with +VIP tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe they're using `<a href="#" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>`, are you sure there's no href like this?
And there's a difference when using different = parsers give different results.
Try using all of them and check for the result `xml` , `html5lib` , `html.parser"`
[Difference between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)
[image: one <code>href</code> = #]

Comment: Oh! I found that there is a   a href="#"   in the same class of my target href, and it is in front of my target so that I got a # instead of my target. Thank you.

Comment: Haha , no problem. JavaScript can be tricky and since I see you interacting with it Selenium is a very useful module,  give it a look at least :D.